# python manage.py migrate returns with django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064... error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am a newbie and I am trying to create a django project on `Windows 8` with `Python 3` and `Django 1.8.6` using `mysql` database

When I execute `python manage.py migrate` I get an error as

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064 ....
```

I have cross checked my settings.py file and everything. In fact the connection is established and sometimes it successfully creates tables`django_content_type` and `django_migrations` and then gives this error and sometimes without creating these tables itself I get this error.

The stack trace printed ends as follows :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")
```

I have also referred and tried to follow the instructions (installed mysql-connector-python-2.1.3) in other similar queries at this site, but nothing seems to be working

The complete stack trace is as follows :

```
D:\pythonLearn\learningDjango\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 207, in execute self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 37, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorvalue
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 192, in execute r = self._query(query)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 356, in _query rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 320, in _do_query db.query(q)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 346, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 445, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 93, in handle executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 19, in __init__self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47, in __init__self.build_graph()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 188, in build_graph   self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations self.ensure_schema()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 53, in ensure_schema editor.create_model(self.Migration)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 289, in create_model self.deferred_sql.extend(self._model_indexes_sql(model))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\schema.py", line 56, in _model_indexes_sql self.connection.cursor(), model._meta.db_table
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\introspection.py", line 142, in get_storage_engine
"WHERE table_name = %s", [table_name])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in __exit__ six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 658, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 207, in execute self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 37, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorvalue
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 192, in execute r = self._query(query)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 356, in _query rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 320, in _do_query db.query(q)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")
```

Comment: so, please put up the code you've executed.

Comment: @hsfzxjy So the only thing that I have written is in settings.py which is as follows : `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'polldb',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'passwd',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',

    }
}`  because I am still trying to create tables through `migrate`

Comment: If you are using the `django.db.backends.mysql` backend with Python 3, then you should be using [`mysqlclient`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#id9), not mysql-connector-python. The docs warn that mysql-connector-python may not work with the latest version of Django, and I have seen other questions from users on Stack Overflow who were having problems with it.

Comment: @Alasdair so presently I have both installed. Do you suggest that I uninstall mysql-connector-python

Comment: @Alasdair mysqlclient was installed using `pip install mysqlclient` - this says that it is installed in `c:\users\vandana\appdata\roaming\python\python34\site-packages` . Do I need to set some environment variable as well

Comment: You can uninstall mysql-connector-python if you're not using it, but I don't think it will solve your problem. You shouldn't have to set any environment variables for mysqlclient.

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback? Do you know which migration causes the error (you can migrate individual apps with `./manage.py migrate appname`.

Comment: @Alasdair I have not yet created any app. As per the tutorials this command must be first tried to see that everything is set up well. I am editing the question to display the complete stack trace

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see what the problem is. Note that if you are just starting out with Django, the easiest backend to use is sqlite3, since it comes bundled with Python.

Comment: @Alasdair yes but I really need to do this. I have been successful with Python 2.7 on my ubuntu system, but it is not working on my windows 8 m/c where I have Python 3 installed

Answer (score 1):

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1")

Need to upgrade mysql to 5.6 or later. This is caused because of DATETIME(6). which is supported 5.6 or lated version.

Reference
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#fractional-seconds-support-for-time-and-datetime-fields

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says ...

> ...for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

This means the query your program passed to MySQL contained the text string `%s`. It looks to me like your program has not substituted a value into that string. It must do so before trying to use the string as a query.

This business of using placeholders in queries is commonplace. Is it possible your query says something like this?

```
 INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (%s)
```

It needs to say this instead

```
 INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('Ban Ki Moon')
```

Comment: this is an error reported on file `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 320, in _do_query` which is python library file. Moreover I have not written any code at all - I am still at the `migrate` stage only

Answer (score 0):

As @krishna chandak said, you should upgrade the `MySQL` version because of `DATETIME(6)`.

## How to update MySQL version:

#### Make sure yum is up-to-date

```
yum update yum
```

#### Install yum-utils (it provides yum-config-manager)

```
yum install yum-utils
```

#### Backup: dump all databases to all_dbs.sql

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables --all-databases -uroot -yourpassword >/root/all_dbs.sql
```

#### Stop MySQL daemon

```
service mysqld stop
```

#### Download latest MySQL

#### ------ for CentOS 6

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-2.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh mysql80-community-release-el6-2.noarch.rpm
```

#### ------ for CentOS 7

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
```

#### Remove old version and install 5.7 version

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable mysql57-community
sudo yum-config-manager --disable mysql80-community
yum remove mysql55-server
yum install mysql57-server
yum update mysql
```

#### Start MySQL

```
service mysqld start
```

#### If you get any errors you have to remove deprecated variables in etc/my.cnf

#### Upgrade existing databases

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

## IF YOU HAME ERROR WITH *.sock

Change config `/etc/my.cnf` by adding

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

and commenting this string

```
# socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then do steps to updating database and return config to previous state.